# Problem with excel, I want to find a way to add values from cells depending if a neighbour cell is green or red

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First time posting here.

I have a problem with Excel/Google Sheets. I want to conditionally add values from different cells depending on a neighbouring cell that we color green or red to know if a payment was made. I want the end result to be the total amount we have received from payments on a single cell. Can you help me with this?

I have tried some combinations with IF but didn't have the desired result mainly because I want it to take the existing information and add everything in a single cell. Do you have any other solutions? Maybe some suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In Excel, a formula can't know the colour of a cell.

Comment: What is the logic behind green or red?

Comment: If you're using a conditional format to color the cells, you could apply that formula to the formula, but you haven't provided the logic on how to determine if a payment was made. Generally if may read like `=IF( [Cell] <= 0, [formula you want when payment was made], [formula for when it wasn't])`

Answer (score 1):

With this very simple macro you can sum the values in range A1:A30 if the interior color in range B1:B30 is red. The result is returned in cell D1.

```
Sub payments()

Dim i, result As Long

For i = 1 To 30
If Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
result = result + Cells(i, 1).Value

End If

Next i
Cells(1, 4).Value = result

End Sub
```

[image: sum by color]

Alternatively you can enter an "x" in an adjacent cell in range C1:C30 if a payment was made and then apply this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A30,C1:C30,"x")
```

[image: sum in excel]

Comment: For OP, the color index may vary from what's provided here, so it may be helpful to record a macro and copy the cell formatting to see what color index appears so you can adjust this accordingly. Judging from their question, I'm unsure if VBA is the best solution for them though this would be good for advanced users who understand how it works.

Comment: [`ColorIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.colorindex) is not a consistent color. It depends on the current color palette. For robust results, use [`Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color).

Comment: Upvoting for the suggestion to add a column, although "PAID" / "UNPAID", or "YES" / "NO" might be a better keyword.